# Return sum of expense on current month in Ember JS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to get my **expenses sum**, but filtered by the **current month**.

```
expenses: computed('transactions.length', 'transactions.@each.amount', function() {
  return this.get('transactions').filterBy('typeOfT','expense').sortBy('date')
}),

filteredExpenses: computed('expenses.length', 'expenses.@each.amount', function() {
    let thisMonth = new Date().getFullYear()+'-'+(new Date().getMonth()+1)
return this.get('expenses').filterBy('date', 'thisMonth').mapBy('amount').reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
}),
```

So trying the `filterBy('date', 'thisMonth')` function didn't work. I thought this would be way easier, but it isn't. Using `mapBy('amount')` and `reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)`I can get the array of all expenses and by using the function I calculate the sum.

My model:

```
export default Model.extend({
  category: DS.attr(),
  name: DS.attr(),
  description: DS.attr(),
  amount: DS.attr(),
  date: DS.attr(),
  typeOfT: DS.attr(),

  user: DS.belongsTo('user')
});
```

Comment: Can you post what your data looks like?

Comment: @stevenelberger I added the model above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% on the month filtering (might need some tweaking), but in general this should give you the current month's expenses:

```
import { computed } from '@ember/object';
import { filterBy, mapBy, sum } from '@ember/object/computed';

// first get all of your expenses in an array by filtering on `typeOfT`:
expenses: filterBy('transactions', 'typeOfT', 'expense'),

// then filter expenses by the current month
currentMonthExpenses: computed('expenses', function() {
  return this.get('expenses').filter(expense => {
    return new Date(expense.get('date')).getMonth() === new Date().getMonth();
  });
}),

// now map all of this month's expenses by their amounts:
currentMonthExpenseAmounts: mapBy('currentMonthExpenses', 'amount'),

// now sum all of the current month's expense amounts:
sumOfCurrentMonthExpenses: sum('currentMonthExpensesAmounts')
```